# Custom view works great in Ice Cream Sandwich, but onDraw not called on Gingerbread

Tags: android, ondraw

I created a custom view by extending View, it draws a simple graph, I add it to my layout using:

```
GraphView graphView = new GraphView(this, values, titles, "Title");
LinearLayout scrollViewLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.scrollViewLinearLayout);
scrollViewLinearLayout.addView(graphView);
```

It functions perfectly under Android 4.0, but it does not show up under Android 2.33. In fact onDraw is not even called under Android 2.33.  It appears that onMeasure is called, because the scrollView the view is being added to expands to allow vertical scrolling.

```
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int height = (titles.length * (24 + 20)) + 80 + (5 / 2) + 10;
    setMeasuredDimension(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, under Gingerbread putting LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, appears to have no effect, as soon as I tried putting in a value equal to the width of the screen everything worked properly.